# Can I install apps on "/home" / home directory instead of "/user" directory?

Tags: software-installation, dual-boot

I am trying to dual boot on my laptop. And i have decided to create two partition in my ssd and hdd. I want create a partition in ssd for "/" root directory and a partition in the hdd for my "/home" directory of my ubuntu setup. And now my question is, Where will be "/usr" user directory will be set? Is it on the ssd partition? And by default, where are apps that i installed is set? I have come to know that its the user directory. Can i change the directory of apps installing to "/home" directory instead of "/usr" directory?
Because, I dont have many space on my ssd. Thanks in advance...

Comment: 1) Having multiple partitions or multiple disks doesn't imply dual boot. Having 2 OS'es does.
2) Are you sure you've googled how to mount different directories on different disks or partitions during installation?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you install your application using [Flatpak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flatpak) it will be installed in your home directory.

Otherwise, you can make a second partition (e.g. /dev/sdb2) on your HDD and mount /usr on that partition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now its clear to me

Answer (score 0):

I just checked my main working install. I do regularly houseclean and have moved all my data in /home (but not settings) into data partition. I wanted user settings on SSD as they also are often accessed, but data is not. Data partition used to be on HDD, but now larger SSD, moved to SSD. I typically create a 30GB partition for / and now using 8.5. Data partition is very large in comparsion, but I do not have lots of data.

```
fred@z170-focal-k:~$ sudo du -hx --max-depth=1 / 2> /dev/null
[sudo] password for fred: 
124K    /mnt
8.0K    /media
497M    /var
4.0K    /opt
4.0K    /srv
1.2M    /root
6.2G    /usr
16K     /lost+found
299M    /home
9.1M    /etc
198M    /boot
4.0K    /cdrom
8.5G    /
```

So you may want data on HDD, but not system. Having /home on HDD is easiest way for a new user as it automatically mounts /home and gives user ownership & permissions. If you use a data partition you have to create mount point, mount it with fstab and give yourself ownership & permissions to use it.

If interested:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1058756/installing-all-applications-on-a-ssd-disk-and-putting-all-files-on-hdd-disk

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response...